# I am trying to downgrade from EE to CE

Tags: magento2

In doing so I am getting this error. Check someone guide me how to solve this?

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key, query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity` MODIFY COLUMN `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity ID", MODIFY COLUMN `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL  COMMENT "SKU", DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
```

Comment: Do you have a 'row_id' in EE as the default primary key?

Comment: Yes exactly it is that

Comment: In EE they add the 'row_id' for the product staging, which does not exist in CE/OS.

Comment: I got that but since I am migrating site from EE to CE, what should I do?

Comment: Have you taken a look at How to Downgrade Magento 2 Commerce to Open Source see https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-downgrade-magento-2-commerce-to-open-source.html

Comment: Yes I followed that but the git extension which are having SQL queries I run them still get this issues